# excel vbaOverflow error

Tags: vba, excel

My Vba code is

```
    Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim arr() As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim arr1() As Variant
    Dim arr2() As Variant
    Dim arr3() As Variant

    Dim wb5 As Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim str As String
    Dim q As Integer
    Dim c As Variant

    Dim u As Date
    Set wb = Workbooks("Contractor Manpower Tracking_SE 03.06.2015.xlsx")
    arr1 = wb.Sheets("SE_Scheme").Range("J4:J36").Value
    arr = wb.Sheets("SE_Scheme").Range("I4:I36").Value
    arr2 = wb.Sheets("SE_Scheme").Range("E4:E36").Value
    arr3 = wb.Sheets("SE_Scheme").Range("F4:F36").Value
    u = wb.Sheets("SE_Scheme").Range("$Q$2").Value
    Workbooks("Scheme1.xlsm").Activate
    For Row = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        For Col = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
        If (IsNumeric(arr1(Row, Col)) And Not (IsNull(arr1(Row, Col)) And IsNull(arr(Row, Col)))) Then
        Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Row + 87, 4) = (arr1(Row, Col) / arr(Row, Col) * 100)
        End If
    Next Col
 Next Row
 End Sub
```

I have two null values in arr and arr1 arrays because of which this error is occuring and the program is terminating. Please help

Comment: A SHOT IN THE DARK... Try this.. Replace `Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Row + 87, 4) = (arr1(Row, Col) / arr(Row, Col) * 100)` by `If arr(Row, Col)<>0 then Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Row + 87, 4) = (arr1(Row, Col) / arr(Row, Col) * 100)`

Answer (score 0):

The shortest way is to add `If` statement checking for 0:

```
If (arr(Row, Col)<>0) Then Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Row + 87, 4) = (arr1(Row, Col) / arr(Row, Col) * 100)
End If
```

Hope this may help.

Comment: You are welcome! I am glad it works for you. Please mark the answer accepted. Best of luck with your project. Kind regards,